# Remove icon gloss effect from an Adobe Air iOS app?

Tags: ios, flash, air, icons

How do you prevent iTunes from adding the default gloss effect when compiling an iOS app using Adobe Air?  Using Adobe Flash CS6. . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to the InfoAdditions element in the application descriptor file:

```
<InfoAdditions> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key> 
        <true/> 
    ]]> 
</InfoAdditions>
```

from : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html

Comment: This works.  I was erroneously using `<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key><string>true</string>`, which kept getting auto-mangled by Flash.  Thanks for the reference!

Comment: And it turns out that this method is also persistent.  Once Flash recognizes the InfoAdditions entry, it will remain in the XML no matter what other changes you make.  In fact, if you want to delete the entry, you have to delete the XML file entirely, which will cause Flash to recreate the XML.  Doing this means that you will have to re-do all the app settings in Flash, though, so make a backup (removing the unwanted entry), then, once the XML is recreated, paste all the settings in the new XML and save it . . . this should be picked up by Flash.

Answer (score -1):

This will require you to add a boolean UIPrerenderedIcon key to the app's info.plist file and set it's value to true.

To do so, follow the steps below:

1. Change the extension of the .ipa file produced by Flash CS6 to .zip.
2. Unzip the file and right-click to view the app's contents, which should be located in a directory named "Payload."
3. Locate and edit the info.plist file, adding the UIPrerenderedIcon key/value pair mentioned above.

Comment: This method will invalidate the IPA.  I have to sign it using Adobe, which is on Windows; would need to know either how to revalidate the IPA or change the PLIST file before compilation.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, my experiences are limited to OSX. On Macs the process of inspecting an app's payload in this way is quite common.

Comment: Either way, I would prefer to have a method that I could use to add the entry *before* compiling the app, and not mess with the IPA afterwards.