# how to edit XML file flash cs6

Tags: ios, xml, flash, air

i'm working in flash pro cs6 and publishing as an ipa file 
(AIR for ios)
now, i'm trying to edit the XML file in order to Remove the icon gloss effect iTunes do.
whith a fue lines of code i funde here

[Remove icon gloss effect from an Adobe Air iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300130/remove-icon-gloss-effect-from-an-adobe-air-ios-app)

but.... well, in the publish setting (ios) i can't replace the XML file that been automaticly made by flash pro. and i can't edit it and save becose flash pro cs6 overwite it.

please help! 
this is such a headache!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question properly, but a simple solution is to edit the `app.xml` file with Notepad or another text editor and then set it to read-only on the file properties. In that way, the Flash CS6 will not have permission to overwrite your file and make the normal publish process from Flash CS6.

Note: Tested and works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work...
Trying to get advanced telemetry enabled in the swf using a Python script as suggested elsewhere and then fool Flash CS6 into packaging the doctored swf.

For ages I was getting Flash to use the swf I'd modified but then the ipa didn't install.There's an error on the iPad when I try to install...  failed to install.

My method to trick Flash is as follows.

Run script on myApp.swf.

Change publish filename to myApp2 or whatever if myApp was original.

Include myApp.swf in Included files to make it added to ipa package.

Change app name and app id on the first two tabs of publish settings so that they DON'T have the 2 on the end.

Make sure that version number and most importantly app id are same as it should be.

Generated myApp-app.xml should refer to myApp.swf not myApp2.swf as a result

End result - ipa installs with old swf with enabled advanced telemetry